# How to clear cache object (memory) through Java

Tags: java, caching

Code snippet used to allocate cache memory:

```
private static Cache cache = CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(CACHE_NAME);

public static HashMap<String, XXX> getxxCodes(int version) {
        HashMap<String, XXX> xxCodes = new HashMap<String, XXX>();
        try{
            Object[] cacheResult = cache.get(Constants.I_XX_CODES_FOR_XXX);
            if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(cacheResult[1])) {
        cache.put(Constants.I_XX_CODES_FOR_XXX, id.loadXXHashMap(version));
                cacheResult = cache.get(Constants.I_XX_CODES_FOR_XXX);
            }
            if(cacheResult[0]!=null){
                xxCodes = (HashMap<String, XXX>)cacheResult[0];
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Exception occured while loading Data from I10_DRG_XX",e);
        }
        return xxCodes;
    }
```

Now at some point of time I need to load some other "version" into the cache memory. Here version can be 1, 2, 3 etc. So the cache first holds version 1 data (Hash map). Now when I am passing 2 which is unavailable in cache it needs to load specific data again into cache, but before that it is better to clear version 1 data. Do we have commands like flush to clear specific data?

I hope I am clear with my question. Thanks for helping.

Comment: What package(s) are Cache and CacheManager coming from? (I'm not aware of these classes existing in the standard Java libraries.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following code and its working correctly,

```
public void flushCache()
    {
        cache.flush(cacheKeyName)
    }
```

This will delete the Instance of cache from memory. 
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the object from the Cache(**Assumption:Weblogic cache**)..It sets the **Time to Live** to "0"

```
Cache cache = getCache();
cache.remove(cacheKey);
```

`getCache()` can be implemented as follows...

```
public Cache getCache(){
    Cache cache = CacheFactory.getCache(cacheKey);
    long ttl=0;
    cache.setTtl(ttl);
    return cache;
}
```